# Using Flutter I have to change MacOS apps name in dock. How can I do that?

Tags: flutter, macos

hello I'm using flutter to make a macOS app. My project name was sayac and when I run the app as macOS app in both window name and dock name (when I hover mouse on icon) says sayac but I want to change that to zikirmatik. I changed CFBundleName in Info.plist and window name is zikirmatik now but dock name is still named sayac. How can I also change that ?

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos#configuring-the-apps-name-bundle-identifier-and-copyright):

> The configuration for the product identifiers are centralized in macos/Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig. For the app’s name, set PRODUCT_NAME, for the copyright set PRODUCT_COPYRIGHT, and finally set PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER for the app’s bundle identifier.

So in your `macos/Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig` you just change `PRODUCT_NAME` param:

```
// The application's name. By default this is also the title of the Flutter window.
PRODUCT_NAME = HELLO WORLD APP
```

Run `flutter clean`, then `flutter run` will show new app name.